# Flutter position widget with top or left throws error

Tags: flutter, dart

```
StreamBuilder
    Listview.builder
       Card(
         child: Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Column(
               children: [
                  CardMenuTitle(id: menu.title),
                  CardMenuImage(menu: menu, index: index),
                  ... ]
                  ...
```

Now in cardmenuimage

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Stack(
  children: [
    Container(), //just tried to add empty container to see if it fixes the problem
    Positioned(
      top: 1, //if I remove this line, it works, 
      child: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        // needed
        color: Colors.transparent,
        child: Image.asset(
          "assets/images/menu/${menu.image}",
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Positioned.fill(
      child: Material(
        color: Colors.transparent,
        child: InkWell(
          splashColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
          onTap: () {
            
          }, // needed
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

}
}

The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
BoxConstraints forces an infinite width.
These invalid constraints were provided to _RenderColoredBox's layout() function
by the following
function, which probably computed the invalid constraints in question:
RenderConstrainedBox.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:279:14)
The offending constraints were:
BoxConstraints(w=Infinity, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)

```
Positioned(
      top: 1, //if I remove this line, it works, 
      child: Container( //removing container solves the problem but image is not displayed
        width: double.infinity,
        // needed
        color: Colors.transparent,
        child: Image.asset(
          "assets/images/menu/${menu.image}",
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

After removing the container from the position widget, the error goes away but image is not displayed.

Answer (score 1):

replace `width: double.infinity` with `width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width`

Comment: error says the `BoxConstraints forces an infinite width` which caused by the Container infinite width.

Comment: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart': Failed assertion: line 588 pos 12:
'size.isFinite': is
not true. after changing the width to MediaQuery.of(context).size.width

Comment: do you have double.infinity in two places replace all of them with `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width`

Comment: After adding height, it fixes the problem. Is it possible to have dynamic height? Because the images in menu are having different heights.

Comment: try removing height parameter and wrap your `cardMenuImage` in `Expanded` widget